# How to change TFS workspaces and access associated local code in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Just learning about workspaces in TFS/Visual Studio 2012. I am testing using a Dev Branch and a Release Branch. I have setup workspaces that map to each of these branches from the server to the local folders.

Now I was assuming, and maybe incorrectly, that when I changed the current WorkSpace via Source Control Explorer, that since the workspace knows the mappings, it would then switch my Solution Explorer to show the local folder files associated with that workspace. This is not the case. Again, I was thinking it would act like FileZilla when you choose a site bookmark, that it then knows to connect to the server side code and then the corresponding local code....

So how do you actually access the local code in the Dev branch and then switch to the Release branch local code? Do you just have to close the Dev solution, then open the Release solution?

I see that this works, but it is confusing to know which version you are working with as the solution name will be the same when it is displayed in the Solution Explorer. You have to maybe r-click and view the properties of the file paths to see which actual version (Dev or Release) that you have opened. Same issue when opening VS and it lists the same solution name under the Recent section...you have to hover over it to see which version you want to open...all in all, it just seems like there is a decent chance that you could confuse the 2 and start coding in Release when you mean to code in Dev... I know you have to be careful, but this definitely doesn't help.

It would be nice, and maybe I missing this, if from when you first open VS that it would give you the option to open a WORKSPACE instead of a solution/project. At least that way, you can name your workspaces to be meaningfully different.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have rely big code bases I usually have a single workplace for all of my dev work. That way I just open any solution that I want.

I use workspaces for other tasks, like admin or merging... Or bug fixing on specific versions.

Comment: I have a Main and Dev workspace and need to switch between them (Dev is current code and Main is the current view of production that I can do bug fixes in if required.) So when you do switch between them, do you just open their respective solutions? There is no way to open a workspace and have it open the associated local project and navigate the source control explorer to the associated server folder?

Comment: No, you need to deliberately change workspace first. As a workspace is irrelevant of dev/prod there is no auto switching...